# Не получается установить Silero

Tags: python, pip

```
pip install silero


Collecting silero
  Using cached silero-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Using cached silero-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Using cached silero-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
  Using cached silero-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install silero==0.1.0, silero==0.2.0, silero==0.4.0 and silero==0.4.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    silero 0.4.1 depends on torch>=1.10.0
    silero 0.4.0 depends on torch>=1.10.0
    silero 0.2.0 depends on torch>=1.10.0
    silero 0.1.0 depends on torch==1.10.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

Говорят иногда помогает если записать с присвоением версии. Но это никак не помогло.

```
pip install silero==0.4.1 


Collecting silero==0.4.1
  Using cached silero-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)           
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.10.0 (from silero) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.10.0
```

Comment: ну вам же пишут про torch. он у вас установлен? если да, то какой версии?

Comment: Он также не встаёт. 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Comment: а python у вас какой версии?

Comment: Изначально поставил 3.11, но потом сменил на 3.9

Comment: Всё, устанавливаю torch. Установить python 3.9 я установил, а сменить забыл. Спасибо за помощь. Думаю дальше пойдёт без инцидентов.

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, для 3.9 максимально доступная версия torch - 1.9.1 . то есть, 1.10х нету. ищите, как можно ставить более старую версию silero соответственно с более старой верcией torch

Comment: Ну да, тут явно в отсутствие `torch` всё упирается.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте установить следующей командой pip install silero --no-deps

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]